# How do I return multiple values from mocked method for different cases?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

```
    new MockUp<SomeClass>() {
        @Mock
        boolean getValue() {
            return true;
        }
    };
```

I want to return a different value from getValue() depending on the test case. How can I do this?

Comment: is there a problem with making new mock-ups or expectations for each test case?

Comment: have you looked at using a result delegate?  http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#delegates

Comment: I'm not sure how to make multiple mockUps of the same method on the same class.  It will just execute the first MockUp.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question with an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: getValue is a dependency in my test unit - it's a public method in the class containing the unit under test.  I have two test cases - one where I need that dependency to return true, and the other where I need it to return false.

Comment: if `getValue` is a method in your class under test, you should not mock it. You should change the underlying conditions (via mocks, etc) to have the method return the expected value. Another less safe mechanism would be to create a "test" subclass of the class under test and control it to return the expected value. Finally, if you must mock, use Mockito's spy mechanism.

Comment: John, that's wrong with mocking a method in the class under test?  This method will have it's own unit test of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have different behavior from the same mocked class in different tests, you need to specify the desired behavior in *each* separate test. For example, in this case:

```
public class MyTest
{
    @Test public void testUsingAMockUp()
    {
        new MockUp<SomeClass>() { @Mock boolean getValue() { return true; } };

        // Call code under test which then calls SomeClass#getValue().
    }

    @Test public void anotherTestUsingAMockUp()
    {
        new MockUp<SomeClass>() { @Mock boolean getValue() { return false; } };

        // Call code under test which then calls SomeClass#getValue().
    }

    @Test public void testUsingExpectations(@NonStrict final SomeClass mock)
    {
        new Expectations() {{ mock.getValue(); result = true; }};

        // Call code under test which then calls SomeClass#getValue().
    }

    @Test public void anotherTestUsingExpectations(
        @NonStrict final SomeClass mock)
    {
        // Not really needed because 'false' is the default for a boolean:
        new Expectations() {{ mock.getValue(); result = false; }};

        // Call code under test which then calls SomeClass#getValue().
    }
}
```

You can instead create *reusable* `MockUp` and `Expectations` subclasses, of course, but they would also be instantiated in each test which needs the specific behavior.

Comment: This is what I had tried before, but it never executed the mockup in the second case.  I think it was because I had forgotten about a mock of the entire class that I had in another place in the test class.